# How to position a second item into the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There's a lot of html here, but it should look very familiar to anyone with a bootstrap site.

```
<body>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="/">Home</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="pull-right nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="##" class="navbar-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Your name here
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/Profile/Profile.cfm">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/?logout">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form>
        <textarea name="Comment"></textarea>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
```

I was able to place the "Save" button at the top right-hand part of the screen with this css:

```
.form-actions {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:25px;
}
```

What I would like to do is give it a fixed-top attribute.  In other words, so that it doesn't scroll off the screen when the user scrolls down.

I can change the html, the css, anything necessary to achieve this goal.  For instance, right now "Your name here" is on the right-hand side of the navbar, but that was on a whim - it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you want the final page to look like, but is this a start?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/R5Q3W/

The important bit is that the form is what you want to 'spy'on, so I wrapped it in a containing div like so:

```
<div class="formWrapper" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">
<form> ...... </form>
</div><!-- close formWrapper div -->
```

(data-offset-top is the distance the page needs to scroll before the affix action kicks-in)

Then I added this CSS to define what you want to happen to this div when it's affixed

```
.formWrapper.affix{
right:0;
top:25px;
width:100%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow!  That's very interesting!  Let me check that out!